# How do I deploy an OpenLaszlo solo application?

Tags: openlaszlo

I have been looking at OpenLaszlo. I could not find how to deploy a solo application..
What do I have to copy or what programs do  I have to run?

I know the deployment type can be dhtml or flash...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For SOLO mode, you take the OpenLaszlo .lzx source "program" (expressed in XML format) and "compile" it into an Adobe Flash .swf file using the lzc utility.

For example, a hello.lzx source would be compiled as follows

lzc hello.lzx

into a Flash application called

hello.sw8.swf

Then you simply embed the .swf into an HTML page as you would any other Flash content. The client browser must have the Adobe Flash Player version 8 or version 9 to play the .swf Flash application.

To see the Flash application work right off the disk of your development machine, just point your browser directly at the local .swf file and it should show up in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenLaszlo documentation contains a section with some information on how to deploy an application:
http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps3.4/docs/deploy/deployers-guide.html#deployers-guide.steps

There's another section in the docs describing the SOLO and proxied deployment mode.
http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps4.9/docs/developers/proxied.html

The documentation can be a bit confusing, since it has not been updated over the past years.

The simplest way to deploy an application is to use the developer console, which is displayed below the OpenLaszlo application in the browser. You'll see a "SOLO" button in the console, which will start the process of generating an embedding HTML page for you OpenLaszlo application, bundle up all static resources into a ZIP file, which can be processed by automated build scripts to generate a new version of your software.

All the compilation and deployment steps can be run from the command line using the "lzc" command for compilation, and the "lzdeploy" command to generate the deployment ZIP file. Both tools can be integrated into Ant. The commands can be found in folder

> $LPS_HOME/WEB-INF/lps/server/bin

Check this blog post in the OpenLaszlo project blog for more information on the lzdeploy tool (which does not seem to be documented in the official documentation):
http://weblog.openlaszlo.org/archives/2008/04/lzdeploy-new-command-line-utility-for-deploying-solo-applications/

Comment: I would not recommend to use the proxied deployment mode any more, since that part of the server has not been well maintained. Most of the proxied mode functionality (transcoding of media files, cross-origin requests) was only needed for Flash version before Flash 8. OpenLaszlo supports cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) for the DHTML/HTML5 runtime (checked into OpenLaszlo trunk 5.0), and for the SWF runtime you can use the crossdomain.xml to allow access to remote webservices directly out of the client.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a similar question regarding automated builds of an OpenLaszlo SOLO application using Apache Ant. The answer contains a full build script to compile either an SWF or DHTML/HTML5 application, including all required resources. The discussion can be found here:
[How to build an OpenLaszlo DHTML application using Apache Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897892/how-to-build-an-openlaszlo-dhtml-application-using-apache-ant)