# Is this build script a valid build script for openlazlo 4.9 compilation

Tags: ant, build, openlaszlo, lzx

Is this a valid ant build script for Open laszlo 4.9. I am not able to build that with this file.

```
<project name="test" default="TestClient" basedir=".">
    <property name="src"   value="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="webappDir" value="../webapp"/>

    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="lzbin" value="${env.LPS_HOME}/WEB-INF/lps/server/bin"/>

    <!-- use the correct compiler script based on platform -->
    <condition property="lzc" value="${lzbin}/lzc">
        <os family="unix"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="lzc" value="${lzbin}/lzc.bat">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>

    <property name="TestClient.lzx" value="${basedir}/src/TestClient.lzx"/>
    <property name="TestClient.swf" value="${basedir}/src/TestClient.swf"/>
    <property name="TestClient.lzx.swf" value="${TestClient.lzx}.swf"/>
    <property name="modules" value="${basedir}/src/modules"/>



    <target name="TestClient" description="compile TestClient.lzx">
        <echo message="${lzc}"/>
        <exec executable="${lzc}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="${TestClient.lzx}"/>
            <arg value='"--runtime=swf10"'/>
        </exec>
        <copy file="${TestClient.lzx.swf}" todir="${webappDir}"/>
        <delete file="${TestClient.swf}"/>
        <delete file="${TestClient.lzx.swf}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="Debug" description="update files on webapp folder from tdc/src">
        <unzip src="${basedir}/../openlaszlo-4.9.0-servlet.war" dest="${webappDir}">            
            <patternset>
                <exclude name="**/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
                <exclude name="**/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
                <exclude name="**/my-apps/copy-of-hello.lzx"/>
            </patternset>
        </unzip>
        <copy file="${TestClient.lzx}" todir="${webappDir}" overwrite="false"/>
        <copy file="${basedir}/../etc/proxy.properties" todir="${webappDir}/WEB-INF/classes" overwrite="false"/>

        <copy file="${basedir}/../webLZDebug.xml" tofile="${webappDir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" overwrite="true" />
        <copy file="${webappDir}/tutorial.html" tofile="${webappDir}/debug.html" overwrite="true" />
        <replace file="${webappDir}/debug.html">
            <replacetoken><![CDATA[lzEmbed({url: 'TestClient.lzx.swf?lzt=swf&folder=calif&servletUrl=http://127.0.0.1:12345/servlet/fixed&eliminatorResource=resources/eliminator.swf&__lzhistconn='+top.connuid+'&__lzhisturl=' + escape('includes/h.html?h='), bgcolor: '#6691B4"',  width: '100%', height: '100%'});]]></replacetoken>
            <replacevalue><![CDATA[lzEmbed({url: 'TestClient.lzx?debug=true&lzt=swf&folder=calif&servletUrl=http://127.0.0.1:12345/servlet/fixed&eliminatorResource=resources/eliminator.swf&__lzhistconn='+top.connuid+'&__lzhisturl=' + escape('includes/h.html?h='), bgcolor: '#6691B4"',  width: '100%', height: '100%'});]]></replacevalue>
        </replace>

        <copy todir="${webappDir}/modules" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${ctbmodules}"></fileset>
        </copy>


    </target>

    <target name="help" description="describes usage">
        <echo>

        </echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have already seen this stackoverflow post.

[How to build an OpenLaszlo DHTML application using Apache Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897892/how-to-build-an-openlaszlo-dhtml-application-using-apache-ant/11900508#11900508)  and i'll be preparing a script like this

But, I just want to confirm that is there any problem with the earlier build script.

Comment: I did a test run with script [How to build an OpenLaszlo DHTML application using Apache Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897892/how-to-build-an-openlaszlo-dhtml-application-using-apache-ant/11900508#11900508), and that one works without any problems on Ubuntu 11.10 with both OpenLaszlo 5.0 trunk and OpenLaszlo 4.9.

Comment: Your script here is not a valid Ant build script, since it's missing the root element, the <project> tag.

Comment: @r.bitter: I have updated the script can you tell me whether its valid script?

Answer (score 1):

In line 28, you have to remove the extra quotes around the **runtime** argument. Instead of

```
<arg value='"--runtime=swf10"'/>
```

it should be

```
<arg value="--runtime=swf10"/>
```

Then, the lzc command has an option -o or --output, where you can define the output file. By default the lzc commmand generates two SWF files, e.g.

```
lzc TestClient.lzx  --runtime=swf10
```

generates TestClient.lzx.swf10.swf and TestClient.swf10.swf. With the -o option, you can directly specify the filename:

```
lzc --runtime=swf10 -o TestClient.swf TestClient.lzx 
Compiling: TestClient.lzx to TestClient.swf
```

Here's the modified section of the build.xml:

```
<property name="TestClient.lzx" value="${basedir}/src/TestClient.lzx"/>
<property name="TestClient.swf" value="TestClient.swf"/>
<property name="modules" value="${basedir}/src/modules"/>

<target name="TestClient" description="compile TestClient.lzx">
    <echo message="${lzc}"/>
    <exec executable="${lzc}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${TestClient.lzx}"/>
        <arg value="--runtime=swf10"/>
        <arg value="-o" />
        <arg value="${TestClient.swf}" />
    </exec>
    <move file="src/${TestClient.swf}" todir="${webappDir}"/>
</target>
```

Don't add a path to the ${TestClient.swf} property, or the lzc command will create the folder structure prepended to the filename. And instead of deleting the generated SWF file after copying, I just move it. Here is the Ant output:

```
raju@T500:~/flex4.6/build-test$ ant
Buildfile: /home/raju/flex4.6/build-test/build.xml

TestClient:
     [echo] /home/raju/src/svn/openlaszlo/trunk/WEB-INF/lps/server/bin/lzc
     [exec] Compiling: /home/raju/flex4.6/build-test/src/TestClient.lzx to TestClient.swf
     [move] Moving 1 file to /home/raju/flex4.6/webapp

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And the resulting directory structure.

```
├── build-test/
│   ├── build.xml
│   └── src
│       └── TestClient.lzx
└── webapp/
    └── TestClient.swf
```